# Select2 retrieving invalid results from the last selected select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am currently having an issue right now where my select2 plugin is showing results from the last selected select box sometimes. Also I also get g.results is null sometimes when I first click the select box or if I type too fast. My code is as follows.

```
        window.currentField = ""; //current product field data
        window.currentCategory = "";   //current product category data

        //lets get some data from the hidden input for providing suggestions via ajax

        $(".suggestive-entry").live('click',function() {
            //alert("click called");
            //alert("test");

            window.currentField = $(this).siblings('input:hidden').attr('data-field'); //get the field attribute
           // alert(window.currentField);
            window.currentCategory = $(this).siblings('input:hidden').attr('data-category'); //get the category attribute
        });

        //formats select2 returned option
        function format(item) { return item.term; };

        //used for suggestive search fields
        $(".suggestive-entry").select2({
            createSearchChoice:function(term, data) { if ($(data).filter(function() { return this.term.localeCompare(term)===0; }).length===0) { return {id:term, term:term};} },
            initSelection : function (element, callback) {
                var data = {id: element.val(), term: element.val()};
                callback(data);
            },
            multiple: false,
            ajax: {
                url: "includes/ajax/map-fields.php",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: function (term, page) {
                    //alert("suggestive called");
                    return {
                        q: term,
                        field: window.currentField,
                        ptype: window.currentCategory
                    };
                },
                results: function (data, page) {
                    return { results: data };
                }
            },

            formatSelection: format,
            formatResult: format
        });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does anyone have any suggestions? Maybe my question is not clear enough?

Comment: Could you provide a jsFiddle?

Comment: thanks for your reply, maybe a better question is how to access data attributes of the hidden input from select2. I am trying to pass data elements in my ajax call as you can see in my data call (field & ptype). I think my issue is that my click event is firing at a different time then select2's onchange event so therefore it is getting field & ptype from the last select box. Looking at my XHR requests makes me think this.

Comment: can you just explain what is hidden field is used for and where it is been placed

Comment: well the select2 plugin renders hidden fields as the modifed text boxes. I have attached data attributes to this element and would like to pass the information contained in these elements to the select2 element that is currently being used. I have tried to accomplish this in using the method I have shown above however sometimes it gives data from the select2 element that was selected previously.

Comment: Please setupd a fiddle in jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to give id to your hidden field, do something like this

```
   data: function (term, page) {
        //alert("suggestive called");
        var data_field = $('#someId').attr('data-field');
        var data_category = $('#someId').attr('data-category');
        return {
                q: term,
                field: data_field,
                ptype: data_category
            };
    }
```

Comment: In my circumstance I had to use the following:

var data_field = $(this).attr('data-field');
                        var data_category = $(this).attr('data-category');

Since my select2 handles all select boxes. Thanks for your help! I tried something similar to this before but it must of been a little bit off so I abandoned the idea.